# R function with list of variables of unknown length

Tags: r

trying to branch out an learn some R, one thing I do often at my job is I pull weighted means by some time specific period variable. I figured out how to do that individually like this:

```
means_by_period <- df %>% 
        group_by(period) %>% 
        summarize(var1 = weighted.mean(var1, wgtvar), 
        var2 = weighted.mean(var2, wgtvar), 
        var3 = weighted.mean(var3, wgtvar), 
        var4 = weighted.mean(var4, wgtvar) 
        )
```

We do this all the time but I am not always going to know how many variables/what variables I am going to be pulling and it would be a pain to edit this code every time, so I built an excel sheet to do it for me, but this seems like a good opportunity to learn how to write a function to do it. Problem is I am not sure how to write it such that it will work. I know my arguments will be: 1. the current data set 2. the period 3. the weighted variable 4. a concatenated vector of my variables?

```
newfunction <- function(df, period, weight, variables)  
        {df %>%  
        group_by(period) %>%  
        summarize(var1 = weighted.mean(var1, weight), 
        var2 = weighted.mean(var2, weight), 
        var3 = weighted.mean(var3, weight), 
        var4 = weighted.mean(var4, weight) ) 
        }
```

I am like 2 weeks into learning so if anyone could give me some pointers on what I'd need to do here that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: In the function arguments you have `variables`, where is it being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 'var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4' are a vector of column names (as strings in the 'variables', then we can convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
newfunction <- function(df, period, weight, variables)  {        
    df %>%  
     group_by({{period}}) %>%  
     summarize(
     !! variables[1] := weighted.mean( !! rlang::sym(variables[1]), {{weight}}), 
    !! variables[2] := weighted.mean( !! rlang::sym(variables[2]), {{weight}}), 
    !! variables[3] := weighted.mean( !! rlang::sym(variables[3]), {{weight}}), 
    !! variables[4] := weighted.mean( !! rlang::sym(variables[4]), {{weight}}) ) 
    }
```

Here, the column names for 'period', 'weight' are assumed to be passed as unquoted, while the 'variables' as a vector of strings

---

As the OP mentioned that 'variables' can be of unknown length, we can loop over the vector of column names ('variables') in `map`

```
library(purrr)
newfunction2 <- function(df, period, weight, variables) {
     map(variables, ~ df %>%
            group_by({{period}}) %>%
            summarise(!! .x := weighted.mean(!! rlang::sym(.x), {{weight}}))) %>%
     reduce(full_join)
  }
```

Comment: These both work, thank you!! I am unfamiliar with lots of these operators and terms so I will have to look into what !! and map() do, as well as the .x

Comment: @bbrinig the `{{}}` is curly-curly operator which does `enquo` + `!!`